# How to rotate a model in ARkit using Raycast and touch in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I am trying to drag or move and rotate a model by touching the device. I am placing it by single touch and rotating it by by double touch. I have added a tag named "Region" to the model. Below is the code. I am attaching this script to the instantiated model.

```
public float rotspeed = 8f;
private RaycastHit vision;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{       

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{       
    if (Input.touchCount == 2 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Debug.Log("Double Touch");
        // Get movement of the finger since last frame
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

        if(Physics.Raycast(Input.GetTouch(0).position,
           this.transform.position,
           out vision))
        {
            Debug.Log("Entered Region");
            if(vision.transform.tag=="Region")
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit Region");
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,
                                 -touchDeltaPosition.x * rotspeed * Time.deltaTime, 
                                 Space.World);
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, 
                                 touchDeltaPosition.y * rotspeed * Time.deltaTime, 
                                 Space.World);
            }
        }           
    }     
}
```

Comment: I have not used ARKit much but i have to ask do you use anchors when you instantiate models. Because if not this rotation wont work properly because your model is not anchored to physical world.

Comment: @alikanat It just shows on the screen...I am using a canvas containing an image to instantiate.Where ever i touch on the screen the same image instantiates.I want it that way.each image i have to rotate individually.That is why I am trying to use Raycast.